# Expected value of projection length

Tags: probability

[image]

The above is taken from: "An Elementary Proof of a Theorem of
Johnson and Lindenstrauss".

My question is why is it clear that $E(L) = \frac{k}{d}$?
I know that:

$E(L) = E(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{x_{i}^{2}}{\|x\|^2}) = E(\sum_{i=1}^{k} \frac{x_{i}^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}^{2}}) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} E(\frac{x_{i}^{2}}{\sum_{i=1}^{d}x_{i}^{2}}) $

Since the numerator and denominator are dependent random variables, I am not sure how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: symmetry.

Long answer: let $y_i$ be the expected value of $\tfrac{x_i^2}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^d x_j^2}$. Since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^d \tfrac{x_i^2}{\sum\limits_{j=1}^d x_j^2}=1$, so does their expectations and $\sum y_i=1$. In addition, all $x_i$ are iid so all $y_i$ are equal and should be equal to $\tfrac{1}{d}$. Summing only $k$ of them results in $\tfrac{k}{d}$.